# "Irony" vs. "happenstance"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nouns

If I were to leave my country because there is a high chance that I will get shot here, and then got shot in the country I immigrate to, would that be ironic or a happenstance?

Comment: It really depends on where you choose to emigrate to. If you choose a riskier country, it would hardly be ironic if you were shot there. If you moved to Shangri-La and were shot, it would be ironic (subclass irony of fate?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could be both unless you are assassinated since that would not be by chance.

> [Happenstance](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/happenstance) - *a circumstance especially that is due to chance*

is just coincidence but it would be ironic for sure.

Comment: We're into the realms of philosophy here. It could be argued either that it's due to chance from someone ignorant of the larger picture, or that theists must believe that there is no such thing as chance.